# SageMaker Serverless Inference error "bring-your-own container image URI does not reside in an Amazon ECR repository within the same AWS account"

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, aws-serverless, amazon-ecr

I am using a custom container hosted in ECR in a different account. The correct permissions should be set up as I can deploy a model to a regular endpoint without issue. However, when I try to deploy as a serverless inference endpoint I get the error

> ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the
> CreateEndpointConfig operation:
>
> The container image URI is not a prebuilt SageMaker algorithm or deep
> learning image, or the bring-your-own container image URI does not
> reside in an Amazon ECR repository within the same AWS account
> creating the endpoint.

Is this a limitation for sagemaker Serverless Inference that the container must be in same account or is there some workaround?

Comment: As of today, serverless inference does require the container to be in the same account.